# Words in Sequence Sharing the Same Root

Tags: single-word-requests, roots

I am trying to figure out what to call these phenomena. For example, a sentence containing the words "specific specifications" or "participants participate", etc. Is there a word to describe this in English?

Comment: I think it's probably something along the lines of a "false tautology", in one sense.  But there may be a term for the actual duplication you see.

Comment: Parenthetically, "...Sharing the Same..." Can you share something different?

Answer (score 2):

This is known as

### Figura Etymologica

Examples

> Gift of giving
>
> Living life
>
> Welcoming welcome

and there is a very lengthy study on the phenomena here: Rhetoric And Repetition: [The Figura Etymologica In Homeric Epic](https://ecommons.cornell.edu/bitstream/handle/1813/13974/Clary,%20Todd.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

Answer (score -1):

The expressions you wrote are instances of **Adj Noun** and **Noun Verb**, respectively. Each expression contains words derived and inflected from a given root. For instance, the lexical morpheme for your first expression is *specify* (or possibly *spec*) and for the second, *part*.  With these base words, we can construct a class of words, known as a word [word family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_family)  by attaching to them *derivational morphemes*, which modify the word's part of speech or meaning OR *inflectional morphemes*, which modify tense and number. So for instance the word family of *spec(-ify*) would be *specification*, *specifier*, *specified*, etc. Because a word family contains different parts of speech, a single word family can generate grammatically structured expressions like the ones you wrote. As far I know, there is no term for such expressions in English, but since roots encode semantic information, it's not surprising that the grammatical expressions derived from a word family are often tautological.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_%28rhetoric%29) to me, though let's wait for 100% sure answer.

Comment: why downvote I wonder?....